# Dapper SQL Call Returning NULL and 0 values

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Working with Dapper on making SQL calls and mapping them to objects.
I am having an issue with SQL Dapper call not mapping correctly to C# Class.

Using ASP.NET Core API and have one controller and one class.

Controller Class

```
 public class DapperController : Controller
{

    private const string connectionString = @"";


    [HttpGet("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var sql = @"SELECT product_name, model_year,list_price
                FROM [production].[products]";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
                connection.Open();

                var product = await connection.QueryAsync<Products>(sql);


                return Ok(product);

    }
    }
}
```

Products Class

```
public class Products
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("product_name")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model_year")]
        public int ModelYear { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("list_price")]
        public double ListPrice { get; set; }

    }
```

Getting back the following data but that is not correct since the database does have data

```
[
  {
    "product_name": null,
    "model_year": 0,
    "list_price": 0
  },
  {
    "product_name": null,
    "model_year": 0,
    "list_price": 0
  }
]
```

When using the above without mapping to class I get the correct data. Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
[
  {
    "product_name": "Trek 820 - 2016",
    "model_year": 2016,
    "list_price": 379.99
  },
  {
    "product_name": "Ritchey Timberwolf Frameset - 2016",
    "model_year": 2016,
    "list_price": 749.99
  }
]
```

Comment: Specify the column names in SQL: `SELECT product_name AS ProductName, model_year AS ModelYear, list_price AS ListPrice`.

Comment: Dapper knows how to open a connection itself

Comment: Do not name classes in the plural. If they are a collection, suffix them with Collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Not sure what I am doing wrong

Because `JsonPropertyName` is for Json serialize instead of Dapper ORM

so that we might need to modify class property as below code or
@Yong Shun as say modify the script alias name which aligns with your c# property (case sensitive)

```
public class Products
{
    public string product_name { get; set; }

    public int model_year { get; set; }

    public double list_price { get; set; }
}
```

I think we might need to use our customer as this link [`ColumnAttribute`](https://gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509) instead of `JsonPropertyName`

Our customer map needs to implement `SqlMapper.ITypeMap`

```
public class Products
{
    [Column("product_name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Column("model_year")]
    public int ModelYear { get; set; }

    [Column("list_price")]
    public double ListPrice { get; set; }

}
```

Also here is a link [V2: [Column] and [Table] Attributes #722](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/722) which dapper official discusses Column mapping attributes for dapper.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now. I was getting confused with JsonPropertyName and  Dapper ORM. Did not work with Column but will investigate which is the correct one to use.

Comment: Don't  violate C# property naming conventions to match database columns, use SQL `AS` to alias the columns so they're to C# convention (if not using some attributes route)